# how to use an es6 template inside of html a tag href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

Hey everyone this is the first time asking a question on here. So here we go. I have a ajax request with json return. I'm trying to now take the response and dynamically create the recipe title but also create an a href with the response data.

```
$( window ).load( function() {
$.get({
  url: window.location.href + ".json"
}).success( function( response ) {
  console.log( response );
  let $title = $( ".js-title" );
  let reviewCount = 0;

  while( reviewCount < $title.length ) {
    let recipe_title = response[reviewCount].recipe.title;
    let href = response[reviewCount].location.href;

    $title[reviewCount].prepend( `<a>${ recipe_title }</a>` ).attr('href', `${ href }`);
    reviewCount++;
  }
});
```

});

I'm having trouble figuring out the href part of things.

Comment: Exactly what is the problem? Also be careful when doing this because if somehow href is getting values set by a user then a user can redirect to a malicious website. Look at XSS and CSRF attacks for more information.

Comment: I just realized that you might be setting href on the wrong element. I don't think prepend will return the <a> element. You will have to find it after you have appended it and then set href on it.

Comment: I'm trying to dynamically create a link based off my ajax response.

Comment: Didn't I take care of that with .attr() ?

Comment: attr function doesn't sanitize user input. For example if I was a user I could do something to set the href to my website and this method will add that to your website. Suddenly I will be able to redirect other users from your website to mine. And that would mean that I will have access to their session cookie which authenticates them on your server. Also try something like this: $("<div>").prepend(`<a>flsfa</a>`).find('a').attr('href','faafdsds').end()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can add href in the template( while creating element ) and no need to use attr function.

example snippet to support above statement:

```js
function prepend() {
  let title = 'something';
  let href = 'something/else'
  $('div').append(`<a href='${href}'>${title}</a>`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="prepend()">Click here</button>
<div></div>
```

To User stand what is wrong with what you did:

No doubt jQuery prepend method is chainable but it will return the element that it applied upon. Therefore if you open inspector you should see href is getting added in `$title[reviewCount]` element.

To do this correct you need to construct the a element and then prepend it.

Example snippet.

```js
function prepend() {
  let title = 'something';
  let href = 'something/else';
  $('div').prepend($('<a></a>').text(`${title}`).attr('href', `${href}`))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="prepend()">Click here</button>
<div></div>
```

To prepend in specific element:

We need to use [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method of Jquery, again this is cahinable.

Use:

```js
$title.eq(reviewCount).prepend($('<a>').text(`${ response[reviewCount].recipe.title }`).attr('href', http: //localhost:3000/recipes/`${recipe_id}`));
```

Comment: I'm taking it step by step. I only return `[object Object]` instead of the template string when i use .prepend($('<a></a>').text(`${myVar}`)

Comment: You got **[object Object]** console.log ryt? No worries it should work on template

Comment: no no it shows on page as `[object Object]` This is how I changed my code.
``` $title[reviewCount].prepend($( '<a>' ).text( `${ response[reviewCount].recipe.title }` ).attr( 'href', `http://localhost:3000/recipes/${recipe_id}` ));
```

Comment: @BrettCole : sorry that I missed this point, when we did `$('<element>')[<index>]`, then the object returned on that index is not a jQuery object instead it is DOM element. Therefore it calls the DOM's prepend method and not jQuery's.

Comment: @BrettCole : use `eq` method from jQuery. I have updated the answer